# Get the inequalities from answers

Tags: inequality

I have two inequalities.
$$x_1\ge x_2
\\x_1 \ge x_3\\ x_1,x_2,x_3 \in {0,1}
$$

The solution of the inequalities is 
$$ (x_1,x_2,x_3) \in {(0,0,0),(1,0,0),(1,1,0),(1,0,1),(1,1,1)}$$

How to get the Inequalities from our answers?(reverse the above process)

Is there any algorithm?

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the $(1,1,1)$ option. And there is no way to get a unique problem that has any solution. It is something like "The solution is $42$. Find the problem"